# How do I get an image URL onmouseover in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the src of any image through plain JavaScript on mouseover.

```
// Retrieve image URL.
document.getElementsByTagName('img').onmouseover = getURL();

function getURL() {
    var URL = this.getAttribute('src');
}
```

I can't bind any of these images to an ID and just getElementById. I have to get any image without modifying the DOM and without jQuery. Looks like getElementsByTagName gets you an array. How would I make this function work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) returns a nodelist which is *array like*. You have to add the event handler to each image or use [event delegation](http://javascript.info/tutorial/event-delegation).

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img')
for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
   imgs[i].onmouseover = getURL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it returns an array, you must specify which array index to get. This should apply the onmouseover function to the first img tag that is found on the page.

```
// Retrieve image URL.
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].onmouseover = getURL;

function getURL() {
    var URL = this.getAttribute('src');
}
```

And to apply this to all images on the page:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
{
   images[i].onmouseover = getURL;
}
```